# How to open a new created Model Razor Page in dotnet core razor pages (3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am starting to develop a new demo from MS Docs Razor Pages with ASP.Net Core 3.1.
I added a new Model Qualification and under Pages the UI by Scaffolding.
Now i am trying to open this new model pages through nav-item but in browser it does not open the index.cshtml page because the href is null. The url https://localhost:44381/qualifications opens the page.

Is there anything wrong?
Thanks a lot for your helps.
Bye

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Qualification">Privacy</a>
</li>
```

[Project files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIVYN.png)

Answer (score 0):

So i find the answer.
It nee to reference to a .cshtml file.

I need to extend the url.

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Qualification/Create">Privacy</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **HTML `<a>` tag**, use `href`:

```html
<a href="/Qualifications">Privacy</a>
```

If you want to use the **.NET Core anchor tag helper**, you need to specify both area name and page name:

```html
<a asp-area="Qualifications" asp-page="/Index">Privacy</a>
```

Note: the area name, from your project structure, should be `Qualifications` (not `Qualification`).

You may check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usage-in-razor-pages) on the official documentation for the details.